# SQL Problema se demora demasiado mi consulta left join

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un problema, mi consulta se demora demasiado en cargar, ya obviamente, tengo miles de datos en las tablas. No se si haya una mejor manera de reestructurarla para que cargue mucho mas rápido.

Gracias

**SQL**

```
Select 
    mt.Rk, 
    mt.Colegios,
    mt.Ciudad,
    mt.Categoria,
    mt.Calificacion,
    mt.Vinculados,
    mt.Url,
    mt2.Rk ingles,
    mt3.Rk lectura, 
    mt4.Rk mate, 
    mt5.Rk social, 
    mt6.Rk ciencia, 
    mt7.Rk top, 
    m.Logo 
from Mat_sapiens mt 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mat_sapiens mt2 on mt.Colegios = mt2.Colegios and mt2.Materia = 'Inglés' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mat_sapiens mt3 on mt.Colegios = mt3.Colegios and mt3.Materia = 'Lectura Crítica' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mat_sapiens mt4 on mt.Colegios = mt4.Colegios and mt4.Materia = 'Matemáticas' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mat_sapiens mt5 on mt.Colegios = mt5.Colegios and mt5.Materia = 'Sociales y Ciudadanas' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mat_sapiens mt6 on mt.Colegios = mt6.Colegios and mt6.Materia = 'Ciencias Naturales' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mat_sapiens mt7 on mt.Colegios = mt7.Colegios and mt7.Materia = 'Top' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Col_micro m on mt.Url = m.ID
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para 174000 registros, me parece que 1 segundo no está nada mal

Comment: La unica forma de acelerar, es mediante indices. Puedes añadir HINTS a la consulta. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html . Aun así, 1 segundo está perfecto. Es un tiempo aceptable, ya que ni filtras ni nada

Comment: Has uso de EXPLAIN para conocer más sobre la ejecución de la misma aunque coincido pues no veo mayor problema con el tiempo

Comment: Una consulta el campo Logo es un varchar o un blob?, de ser así podrías hacer una consulta omitiendo ese campo ?.

Comment: preferí agregar los campos o columnas faltan tes para no recorrer las filas una y otra vez  igualmente gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

¿Porqué usas left outer join?

quita el outer y solo deja left join prueba y mira cuanto tarda
Los outer se ejecutan aparte de la consulta original, eso es lo que logrado ver
cuando a veces me toca que optimizar consultas y uso el visualizador de costo
de sql, veo que manda los outer aparte y allí los procesa y luego los une
de nuevo a la consulta original.

Aunque también a una computadora le es más difícil procesar cadenas a procesar números.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]